# How do I stop AutoMapper from making two identical SELECT statements with NHibernate?

Tags: sql, nhibernate, automapper, projection

I have an entity called `Incident` and a DTO called `IncidentDTO`. For now, `IncidentDTO` simply looks like this:

```
public class IncidentDTO : Incident
{
    // empty until I can get AutoMapper working correctly
}
```

I'm trying to pull a list of all the `Incidents` in the database and convert them to DTOs using this code:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Incident, IncidentDTO>();

using (var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    var incidents = session.Linq<Incident>();
    var incidentDTOs = Mapper.Map(incidents, new List<IncidentDTO>());
}
```

This code works fine, except when I use NHProf to look at the SQL statements being generated, I get this:

```
SELECT ... FROM [Incident] this_
SELECT ... FROM [Incident] this_
```

The two SELECT statements are exactly identical. Why does AutoMapper generate two identical SELECT statements, and how do I prevent it from doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A guess: Enumerating IQueryable creates a separate select for every item. Solve it with enumerating IList.

```
var incidents = session.Linq<Incident>().ToList();
```

I would probably do this to prevent another problem.

```
int someReasonableNumber = 1000;
var incidents = session.Linq<Incident>().Take(someReasonableNumber).ToList();
```

This is just a guess, not something I really know.

Comment: That did it, thanks! I didn't consider enumerating the queryable first. As for the unbound set, that's not a problem because I don't foresee the `Incident` count ever going over 200.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related with this [issue](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/05/02/CombatingTheSelectN1ProblemInNHibernate.aspx):

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not a SELECT N+1 problem. The `Incident` is not associated with anything else.